# Cant get RSS feed to work on joomla 1.5

Tags: php, joomla, rss

I have a problem with RSS feeds in Joomla 1.5.

I use Joomla 1.5 and custom component. I tried to add rss feeds. I don't know what is the problem, but no data is displayed in firefox google reader.
I tested with Chrome and it displays information, but only pure XML (not styled). And if I tried google reader with Chrome, then no information again.

Only thing that appears in google reader, is the site description. And instead of information, I only get "(title unknown)".
This is the file that takes news and puts them into RSS feed. Maybe somebody can understand what is wrong with it :).

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI('php://output');
$xml->startDocument("1.0");
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('rss');
$xml->writeAttribute('version', '2.0');
$xml->writeAttribute('xmlns:g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
$xml->startElement("channel");
$xml->writeElement("title", $mainframe->getCfg('sitename'));
$xml->writeElement("description", $mainframe->getCfg('MetaDesc'));
$xml->writeElement("link", JURI::root());

if($this->projects){
   // start listings
   foreach ($this->projects as $project){

      $xml->startElement("item");
        $xml->writeElement("g:title", $project[title] );
        $xml->writeElement("g:description", $project[description] );
        $xml->endElement();
   }
}

$xml->endElement(); // rss
$xml->endDocument();
$xml->flush();
```

This is corresponding xml

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>MyProject</title>
<description>
My project description
</description>
<link>http://mysite.com</link>
<item>
<g:title>Copywriter</g:title>
<g:description>...</g:description>
</item>
<item>...</item>
<g:title>Design Manager</g:title>
<g:description>...</g:description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

[And this is what i get in google reader](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/readerf.gif/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post your output, but at least you are missing one `endElement`: You need one for the `rss`, and oone for the `channel`, don't you?

Comment: as it seems, output has both </channel> and </rss>.

Comment: Also, google reader has an annoying cache (one example is feed name, if it wasn't set the first time you loaded it, it will be a lot of trouble to fix that). Maybe try changes with a new filename and re-check in reader.

Comment: I tried changing filename after which Google reader gave me this: "The feed being requested cannot be found.". Then I tried again with same filename and got that message as before "(title unknown)".  :(